# Code block usage { } in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I was wondering why code block was used in this example below:

```
possibly_hanging_job & { sleep ${TIMEOUT}; eval 'kill -9 $!' &> /dev/null; }
```

This could have been written like this ( without using code block as well) ..right ?

```
possibly_hanging_job & 
sleep ${TIMEOUT}
eval 'kill -9 $!' &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Putting the last two commands in braces makes it clear that “These are not just two additional commands that we *happen* to be running after the long-running process that might hang; they are, instead, integral to getting it shut down correctly before we proceed with the rest of the shell script.” If the author had instead written:

```
command &
a
b
c
```

it would not be completely clear that `a` and `b` are just part of getting `command` to end correctly. By writing it like this:

```
command & { a; b; }
c
```

the author makes it clearer that `a` and `b` exist for the sake of getting `command` completely ended and cleaned up before the *actual* next step, `c`, occurs.

Comment: Maybe you meant `command && { a; b; }`? A single `&` sends `command` to the background and `a` and `b` run immediately.

Comment: But — the question is about using `&` to run a job in the background, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I even wonder why there's an `eval`. As far as I see it should also work without that.

Regarding your actual question:
I guess the code block is there to emphasize that the `sleep` belongs to `kill`. But it's not necessary. It should also work like this:

```
possibly_hanging_job & sleep ${TIMEOUT}; kill -9 $! &> /dev/null
```